# How to make placeholder checked in EntityType with expaned=true

Tags: php, forms, symfony, radio-button

I am using `EntityType`.

```
$builder
        ->add('defaultAnswer', EntityType::class, [
            'expanded' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'No default answer',
        ]);
```

It shows radio inputs, but placeholder radio input is not checked. How to make checked it?

There is exists closed issue about ChoiceType: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15487 , but I do not want to specify choises explicitly.

Also, placeholder radio input is not pass through choice_attr callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension for the EntityType to transpose the value of the option 'placeholder' to the choices :

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Extensions;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class EntityExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {  
        $resolver->setDefault('choices',function(Options $options, $choices){
                    return array(''=>$options['placeholder'])+$choices;
                });
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

Register the extension in service.yml :

```
services:
    form_extension.entity:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Extensions\EntityExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType }
```

Comment: I like it, but it looks too complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you (place holder and empty_data):

```
        ->add('PetType', EntityType::class,  ['label' => 'Type of pet',
                                              'class' => 'AppBundle:PetType',
                                              'choice_label' => 'name',
                                              'placeholder'   =>'Choose pet type',
                                              'empty_data'  => null,
```